# Testing React Form using Axios to post onSubmit method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I'm new to JavaScript and Testing. I used 'npx create-react-app' as a starting point. I've searched the forums but the code is very different.

**CreatPost.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/posts', {
      title
    });
    // clear title
    setTitle('');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input
            value={title}
            onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**axios.js** mock file

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
  post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue()
  };
```

What I have tried based on research here:

**CreatePost.test.js**

```
import * as axios from 'axios';
import request from 'supertest';
import CreatePost from '../CreatePost';


it('returns a 201 on successful post', async () => {
  axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
  return request(CreatePost)
    .post('/posts')
    .send({ 
      title : 'My first post'
    })
    .expect(201);
});
```

**Error from the test**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementationOnce' of undefined
       5 |
       6 | it('returns a 201 on successful post', async () => {
    >  7 |   axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
         |              ^
       8 |   return request(CreatePost)
       9 |     .post('/posts')
      10 |     .send({
```

*I'm most certainly dazed and confused. Any working examples would be greatly appreciated.*

Second Attempt with axios-mock-adapter
**CreatePost.test.js**

```
import CreatePost from '../CreatePost';
import mockedAxios from 'axios-mock-adapter';


it('returns a 201 on successful post', async () => {
  mockedAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
  return request(CreatePost)
    .post('/posts')
    .send({ 
      title : 'My first post'
    })
    .expect(201);
});
```

TypeError: axios.create is not a function

```
  1 | //import request from 'supertest';
  2 | import CreatePost from '../CreatePost';
> 3 | import mockedAxios from 'axios-mock-adapter';
    | ^
  4 |
```

Comment: try `axios-mock-adapter`

Comment: made an attempt with `axios-mock-adapter`, now getting a new error.

Comment: come on show me, maybe on prv msg

Comment: My attempt was added to the post at the bottom: `Second Attempt with axios-mock-adapter.`  It's throwing this error: `TypeError: axios.create is not a function`.  Also, I haven't read the Stack Overflow Users Guide yet, so I have no idea how to send a prv msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a canonical usage of `axios-mock-adapter`:

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const resp = 'success';

mock.onGet().reply(201, resp);
```

But I don't think you know what you're doing...
Please read docs first and ask questions later. Also, I recommend tutorials of `jest` and `enzyme` fundamentals first :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  I haven't used JavaScript is several years as I've been creating services with C# and Dot Net Core for the past 5 years for HPE.  I've never written JavaScript tests, so sorry for my lack of knowledge.  I was able to use the `const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);` and got it working after also adding `await waitFor(() => onSubmit())   and expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`   Also,  a Get would return a 200, success and a Post would return a 201, created. Thanks for your assistance.